# Setting own ViewPager error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I am using fragments and as I want to disable swiping mode in the application I am trying to use the `CustomViewPager` as suggested here: [how to disable viewpager adapter on touching specific views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342630/how-to-disable-viewpager-adapter-on-touching-specific-views) and here: [how to disable ViewPager swiping using android-support-v4.jar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498402/how-to-disable-viewpager-swiping-using-android-support-v4-jar-in-android).
Tried to follow this but with no luck. What I am trying to achieve is that on the button click application will not follow swpie gestures between fragments. For now, even if I disable swiping on startup it is all fine.

Used snippet:

```
package com.receive.bluereceive;

public class Main extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
private CustomViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());        


    mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
            // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
            // Tab.
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });


    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
        // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
        // listener for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }   
}

public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager{

    public CustomViewPager(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the .xml of the `CustomViewPager`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.receive.bluereceive.CustomViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And lastly, the error I am getting:

```
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.receive.bluereceive/com.receive.bluereceive.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.receive.bluereceive.CustomViewPager
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.receive.bluereceive.CustomViewPager
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:323)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at com.receive.bluereceive.Main.onCreate(Main.java:101)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    ... 11 more
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.receive.bluereceive.CustomViewPager" on path: /data/app/com.receive.bluereceive-2.apk
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
01-15 03:06:14.482: E/AndroidRuntime(29489):    ... 20 more
```

What is causing the trouble? I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. Would be glad if I start the application anyhow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that inflator is unable to find your class. Please declare the CustomViewPager class in its own file and instantiate it in xml using its proper package path.